# Is it possible to set up IPSec on a linux virtual machine host to connect to an Azure virtual network

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, ipsec, azure

We run some virtual machines in an onsite Ubuntu based server with guests being a mixture of Windows Server and Ubuntu. We're also setting up some Windows Azure virtual machines and ideally would like to connect the two.

I've set up a virtual network on Azure but to connect externally it requires an IPSec connection setting up on the router. Is it possible to set up the Ubuntu host box with IPSec routing so that the virtual guests can connect to the Azure network? Are there any other better ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I've used strongswan for ipsec on Ubuntu.  It's a bit annoying for personal use, but in ways that suggest it's more suited to servers :).

Presumably you don't mind your host machine being able to connect to Azure (as well as the  VMs it hosts).

Then using a routed virtual network (as opposed to the usual bridge) would work nicely... with one glaring caveat.  http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Networking

f you're moving from bridged networking to routed, that means no more LAN->VM communication, not without extra configuration.  This is getting tautological, but you'd need to configure your router to route VM traffic towards the host.

I don't think there's a sensible way round it.  So assuming you want LAN->VM communication, you'll still have to reconfigure your router.  (You just won't have to get it to do ipsec).